# Method does not affect my final answer in Java

Tags: java

My program prints the final salary as what calSalary will print which is 40 but AddSal and AddWork do not affect my answer. I have tried many ways to resolve the issue but it still does not work.

```java
class Employee {

    float amount;
    float salary;
    int hoursWorked;

    public Employee(float amount, int hoursWorked){
        this.amount = amount;
        this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    }

    public float calSalary(){
        this.salary = amount * hoursWorked;
        return salary;
    }

    public float AddSal(){
        if(salary < 500){
            return salary + 10;
        }
        else return salary;
    }

    public float AddWork(){
        if(hoursWorked > 6) {
            return salary + 5;
        }
        else return AddSal();
    }

    public void finalSalary(){
        salary = AddSal();
        salary = AddWork();
        salary = calSalary();
        System.out.println(salary);

    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee John = new Employee(10, 4);
        John.finalSalary();

    }
}
```

Comment: The `calSalary()` method only uses the variables `amount` and `hoursWorked` to calculate the value. That is the reason the two other methods which change the value of `salary` have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but clearly addSal() and addWork() should change your class variables and not simply return them.

```
public float AddSal(){
    if(salary < 500){
        salary += 10;
    }
    return salary;
}

public float AddWork(){
    if(hoursWorked > 6) {
        hoursWorked += 5;
    }
    return hoursWorked ;
}
```

It also seems like they shoudln't return anything, and simply mutate the values. Only calcSal() should return the calculated salary, based on `hoursWorked` and `salary` values.

Also, note that calcSalary also mutates `salary`, which I guess is not what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Your calSalary Method sets your salary hardly to `salary = amount * hoursWorked`.
So whatever you do before will be ignored.
So what you have to do is something like `salary = salary + (amount * hoursWorked)`. Atleast if this is what you want to achive. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the base salary be computed in the constructor as you already have all the informations, then you decided whether or not to call method that ajustate the salary if needed, that methods must just return a value to add to the base salary

```
public Employee(float amount, int hoursWorked) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    this.salary = amount * hoursWorked;
}

public int checkLowSalary() {
    if (salary < 500) {
        return 10;
    }
    return 0;
}

public int checkHoursWorked() {
    if (hoursWorked > 6) {
        return 5;
    }
    return 0;
}

public void finalSalary() {
    int moreSalaryIfLow = checkLowSalary();
    int moreSalaryIfWorkLot = checkHoursWorked();
    System.out.println(salary + moreSalaryIfLow + moreSalaryIfWorkLot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be that you don't initialise the `salary` variable. When you create an object Employee, you only pass the values of `amount` and `hoursWorked`, so `salary` has no value. I think that's why the other methods don't do anything

I would change the constructor an give a value to `salary`.

```
public Employee(float amount, int hoursWorked){

this.amount = amount;
this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
//give a default value to salary, 200 for example.
this.salary = 200;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

class Employee {

```
float amount;
float salary;
int hoursWorked;

public Employee(float amount, int hoursWorked){
    this.amount = amount;
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
}

public float calSalary(){
    this.salary = this.salary + (amount * hoursWorked);
    return salary;
}

public float AddSal(){
    if(salary < 500){
        return salary + 10;
    }
    else return salary;
}

public float AddWork(){
    if(hoursWorked > 6) {
        return salary + 5;
    }
    else return AddSal();
}

public void finalSalary(){
    salary = AddSal();
    salary = AddWork();
    salary = calSalary();
    System.out.println(salary);

}
```

}

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Employee John = new Employee(10, 4);
    John.finalSalary();

}
```

}

The calculated value coming for salary variable from AddSal() + AddWork() get overrided
you have to add existing value then add.

Comment: in calSalary() you have to do the changes